# Myriad Pro Font Free Alternative

Tags: font-recommendation

I've already created a design for an iOS application using Adobe Illustrator default font (Myriad Pro).
Can I use this font in development too? (Create an app as a product).
As far as I searched, I think that I can not use it because there is no license for that.
In this case, are there any alternatives that can be used instead of Myriad Pro ?

Answer (score 1):

Myriad Pro is an Adobe font, it looks like you can purchase the license for a good price if you only used a few weight variations. There are a few options if your stuck wanting this font:

http://www.krolldesign.net/tech/css/myriad_font.php

Otherwise this post has some ideas for alternatives etc.:

[Web Safe Alternative to Myriad Pro Font?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/350/web-safe-alternative-to-myriad-pro-font)

Answer (score 1):

you probably won't ,like my answer if you are a designer,  but ;)

Arial it is a font close to myriad pro. Have work on replacement for myriad pro just some time ago and finish paying adobe typekit to be able to do what ever i want with myriad pro. But as a said Arial it is close on a lot of letters.

Best luck